# Hash function over numbers that preserve addition and multiplication

Tags: hash, homomorphic-encryption

I wonder if there is a known hash function that for any $x$, $y$ which are numbers in a certain range with certain accuracy (I guess one can think of them as integers?), you can define two functions corresponding to addition and multiplication such that:

$h(x) \# h(y) = h(x+y)$

and

$h(x) \cdot\cdot h(y) = h(x \cdot y)$.

Edit: I now see it is slightly duplicated with [Is it possible to subtract/multiply numbers using homomorphic encryption?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9697/is-it-possible-to-subtract-multiply-numbers-using-homomorphic-encryption)

Comment: What security properties are you looking for this 'hash function'?  Preimage, second preimage, collision resistance?  Something that actually has a fixed output length independent of the input size?

Comment: It is not duplicate, they are not hash function.

Comment: I remember a similar question but couldn't find it.

Comment: I agree with poncho here; I don't see how you can have such a hash function without dropping at least some of the common properties of a generic cryptographically secure hash function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any practical implementation of a homomorphic hashing or signature scheme?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6497/are-there-any-practical-implementation-of-a-homomorphic-hashing-or-signature-sch)

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage Would it be an issue that there are two operations required in this question? I presume that you could perform repeated addition for smaller numbers, but that would not be the same as fast multiplication...

Comment: I think finding preimages could be easier than the generic attack. However, the question is vague. One really needs to define the operation on the range of the hash. The addition has only one carry but multiplication doubles the output. To analyze one has to define the function properly.