# How to add ciphered numbers under benaloh's scheme?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

In the answer for [Is it possible to subtract/multiply numbers using homomorphic encryption?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9697/is-it-possible-to-subtract-multiply-numbers-using-homomorphic-encryption) it says:

> To add two encrypted numbers, one could use Benaloh, Damgård–Jurik, or several other known partially homomorphic cryptosystems. (Many of these "addition-only" cryptosystems can also be tweaked to support subtraction.

But I couldn't write down a way to sum two ciphered numbers with Benaloh's scheme neither find the mathematics for this on the forum.

So, how to sum numbers ciphered under benaloh's scheme without decrypting them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benaloh_cryptosystem), it says that encryption in Benaloh's scheme takes the form:

$$E_r(m) = y^mu^r\bmod n$$
I'll actually write it as:
$$E_r(m;u) = y^mu^r\bmod n$$
Where $m$ is the message (in $\mathbb{Z}_r$) to be encrypted, and $u\in\mathbb{Z}_n^*$ should  be uniformly random. The other parameters $y, r, n$ are of course important for the scheme, but will not be important to discuss the additive homomorphic properties of the scheme.

The trick here is to note that messages are "in the exponent". So if we want to *add* the messages, we'll have to *multiply* the ciphertexts. If we do this, we'll see that:
$$E_r(m_0)E_r(m_1) = (y^{m_0}u_0^r)(y^{m_1}u_1^r) = y^{m_0+m_1}(u_0u_1)^r\bmod n = E_r(m_0+m_1;u_0u_1)$$
This will be a valid Benaloh ciphertext of $m_0+m_1$ (we technically should verify that $u_0u_1$ is distributed uniformly randomly over $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$, but this is not difficult).

Note that this homomorphic property is **very** similar to that of (unpadded) RSA, where ciphertexts take the form $E(m) = m^e\bmod N$. Of course there is the difference here that RSA must be padded to be secure, and this padding ususally removes the homomorphic property.

Comment: I was concerned if I could "extract" mod n out of equation when multiplying the ciphers. But you made it clear, thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem! For a self-contained answer to that question, you can do that because $(a\bmod n)(b\bmod n) = (ab)\bmod n$. While not relevant to this current discussion, $(a\bmod n) + (b\bmod n) = (a+b)\bmod n$ as well. These two properties mean that $\bmod n$ is what is known as a "ring homomorphism".